# How to specify DLL path in Java Netbeans environement so that application started from DIST directory can find it

Tags: dll, netbeans, javafx

Am writing a JavaFx application on 64 bits computer using third part DLL (lpsolve55.dll).
In the Netbeans environement, i can run the application and perform calculation using the DLL.
But if i run the application from the DIST directory, i can run the Application but can't perform any calculation.
It seems that the application doens't find the DLL.
Can someone give me any idea how to configure my application environement to run the application from the DIST directory and perform calculation using the DLL.
Thanks in advance.